# how to obtain a username from oauth key in twitter

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth

I am working with twitter's oauth, and ive run into a weird problem.

How do i get a user's profile information using just their token and secret?

Here is what im using now

```
    function OauthGetProfile($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $oauthtoken, $oauthsecret){

$to = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $oauthtoken, $oauthsecret);
$content = $to->OAuthRequest('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml', array('count' => '50'), 'GET');

return $content;
}
```

Im not sure how to get this, the api calls to get your profile require you specify the persons profile, which i need their ID to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [verify credentials call](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/verify_credentials) method call. 
http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.xml

Answer (score 1):

I think now you must use url "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.xml" because the URL without "api." will not work now.

the result will be like below xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <id>622181643</id>
  <name>ddMobile</name>
  <screen_name>fff screen_name</screen_name>
  <location></location>
  <description></description>
  <profile_image_url>http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/6456456/qxuz5r09e1x9ri5cadv5_normal.jpeg</profile_image_url>
  <profile_image_url_https>https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/45645645/qxuz5r09e1x9ri5cadv5_normal.jpeg</profile_image_url_https>
  <url></url>
  <protected>false</protected>
  <followers_count>2</followers_count>
  <profile_background_color>C0DEED</profile_background_color>
  <profile_text_color>333333</profile_text_color>
  <profile_link_color>0084B4</profile_link_color>
  <profile_sidebar_fill_color>DDEEF6</profile_sidebar_fill_color>
  <profile_sidebar_border_color>C0DEED</profile_sidebar_border_color>
  <friends_count>3</friends_count>
  <created_at>Fri Jun 29 19:44:37 +0000 2012</created_at>
  <favourites_count>0</favourites_count>
  <utc_offset>-14400</utc_offset>
  <time_zone>Atlantic Time (Canada)</time_zone>
  <profile_background_image_url>http://a0.twimg.com/i6ages/themes/theme1/bg.png</profile_background_image_url>
  <profile_background_image_url_https>https://si0.twimg.com/ima6es/themes/theme1/bg.png</profile_background_image_url_https>
  <profile_background_tile>false</profile_background_tile>
  <profile_use_background_image>true</profile_use_background_image>
  <notifications>false</notifications>
  <geo_enabled>false</geo_enabled>
  <verified>false</verified>
  <following>false</following>
  <statuses_count>8</statuses_count>
  <lang>en</lang>
  <contributors_enabled>false</contributors_enabled>
  <follow_request_sent>false</follow_request_sent>
  <listed_count>0</listed_count>
  <default_profile>true</default_profile>
  <default_profile_image>false</default_profile_image>
  <is_translator>false</is_translator>
  <status>
    <created_at>Wed Sep 05 20:33:56 +0000 2012</created_at>
    <id>24344689170516</id>
    <text>Hap6the last day of our $0 handset sale! http://t.co/iAjai6ye</text>
    <source>&lt;a href=&quot;http://te6ot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Wind Mobile Self Care - SIT&lt;/a&gt;</source>
    <truncated>false</truncated>
    <favorited>false</favorited>
    <in_reply_to_status_id></in_reply_to_status_id>
    <in_reply_to_user_id></in_reply_to_user_id>
    <in_reply_to_screen_name></in_reply_to_screen_name>
    <retweet_count>0</retweet_count>
    <retweeted>false</retweeted>
    <geo/>
    <coordinates/>
    <place/>
    <possibly_sensitive>false</possibly_sensitive>
    <contributors/>
  </status>
</user>
```

reference :[http://twitterapi.pbworks.com/w/page/22554689/Twitter%20REST%20API%20Method%3A%20account%C2%A0verify_credentials](http://twitterapi.pbworks.com/w/page/22554689/Twitter%20REST%20API%20Method%3a%20account%C2%A0verify_credentials)